# Cleanup data for every test iteration

Tags: visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I create Visual Studio 2012 Test Project. I test some web application with data in grid. 
First I created Test Method for delete data from the grid. For the first time I run the test it works correctly. The next time when I run my test method the test fails.
Is there some line of code which adds value in the grid every time before I run my delete test method?
Also I have Edit and Add method. The same question for those actions.First time editing data works fine but the next test fails. First I add data in the grid test success but the next run says that is duplicate.
Can somebody suggest me some instructions or another site where it is done.

Answer (score 0):

A test should have the correct environment set before it is run. For test that delete something, the object to be deleted should be there before the test runs. You could write another test that adds the data and state that the two tests MUST be run in the correct order.

Some people prefer tests to be independent so that they do not require other tests to have been run first. The reason being that (for your scenario) if the add-data test fails then the delete-data test is bound to fail. One solution is to have a bigger and self contained test, a test that adds a record, checks that the record has been added, deletes the record and finally checks that the record has been deleted.